# update queries for multiple data in a single run in mongodb & node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to update multiple records (more than 100).
my records are like

```
data = [{_id : 1 , name : "AAA"}, {_id : 2 , name : "AAB"}, ................}]
```

One method is to apply forEach & update each record but I want to execute without foreach like bulk update or something.
The desired result is :

```
data = [{_id : 1 , name : "XXX"}, {_id : 2 , name : "XXY"}, ................}]
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Do you want to replace A by X, B by Y or altogether different?

Comment: No, it's like names Aman to Akash, Alice to Bethany.

Comment: ok, how do you have the mapping? For this id, this has to be updated such information. What format of the source information?